# Looking for the right query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table called `document_histories`. An example of my table:

```
id   | assembly_order_id | document_type | document_year | document_number | document_date | created_at          | updated_at
2839 | 1287              | ub            | 2019          | 928             | 2019-03-18    | 2019-03-18 14:00:27 | 2019-03-18 14:00:27
2861 | 1287              | us            | 2019          | 881             | 2019-03-19    | 2019-03-19 16:31:06 | 2019-03-19 16:31:06
2862 | 1287              | us            | 2019          | 882             | 2019-03-20    | 2019-03-20 16:39:06 | 2019-03-20 16:39:06
2896 | 1287              | ul            | 2019          | 932             | 2019-03-25    | 2019-03-25 10:55:10 | 2019-03-25 10:55:10
```

What I'm trying to do is list the time it takes from one document to another.
For example:
`#2839` is our starting point (ub). The `document_date` is 2019-03-18. Now I want the lowest `document_date` of the row that has the same `assembly_order_id` and where the `document_type` is `us`

So we'd have something like this:

```
id   | assembly_order_id | document_type | document_year | document_number | document_date | created_at          | updated_at           | *date_diff*
2839 | 1287              | ub            | 2019          | 928             | 2019-03-18    | 2019-03-18 14:00:27 | 2019-03-18 14:00:27  | *1* (2019-03-19 - 2019-03-18)
```

This is only 1 difference, but I also want the time difference between `us` (lowest date) and `ul`(latest/highest date) and between `ub` (lowest date) and `ul` (latest/highest date)

I tried following query, but this isn't fully working as it is returning a lot of null values in the 'time_until_assembly', 'assembly_time' and 'total_delivery_time' columns:

```
SELECT
    ub.*,
    @time_until_assembly:= DATEDIFF((SELECT us.document_date FROM document_histories us WHERE us.document_type = 'us' AND us.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id LIMIT 1), ub.document_date) AS time_until_assembly,
    DATEDIFF((SELECT ul.document_date FROM document_histories ul WHERE ul.document_type = 'ul' AND ul.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id LIMIT 1), @time_until_assembly) AS assembly_time,
    DATEDIFF((SELECT dl.document_date FROM document_histories dl WHERE dl.document_type = 'ul' AND dl.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id LIMIT 1), ub.document_date) AS total_delivery_time
FROM
    document_histories ub
WHERE
    ub.document_type = 'ub'
```

As this didn't have the correct output, I tried a different approach:

```
SELECT
    ub.*,
    ub.document_date as ub_date,
    us.document_date as us_date,
    ul.document_date as ul_date,

    DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, ub.document_date) as total_days_delivery,
    DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, us.document_date) as total_days_assembly,
    DATEDIFF(us.document_date, ub.document_date) as total_days_order
FROM
    document_histories ub, document_histories us, document_histories ul
WHERE
    ub.document_type = 'ub' AND
    us.document_type = 'us' AND
    ul.document_type = 'ul' AND
    us.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id AND
    ul.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id
ORDER BY
    ub.document_date ASC,
    us.document_date ASC,
    ul.document_date DESC
```

But this returns a list with repeated values, having different `total_` values.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Can you recommend a good tutorial/video where they explain all this? I've been looking on the web and been reading many pages about all the different JOIN types, but I can't figure out how to us them properly in this case. Especially since the other rows I need are in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers above I made following query to fully achieve my goal:

```
SELECT
    ub.id, ub.assembly_order_id, ub.document_type, ub.document_year, ub.document_number,    ub.document_date as order_date,    ul.document_date as delivery_date,    us.document_date as assembly_date,    DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, ub.document_date) as delivery_days,    DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, us.document_date) as assembly_days
FROM
    `document_histories` ub
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        assembly_order_id, document_date
    FROM
        `document_histories`
    WHERE document_type = 'ul'
    GROUP BY assembly_order_id
    ORDER BY document_date DESC
) ul ON ul.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        assembly_order_id, document_date
    FROM
        document_histories
    WHERE document_type = 'us'
    GROUP BY assembly_order_id
    ORDER BY document_date ASC
) us ON us.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id
WHERE
    ub.document_type = 'ub'
ORDER BY `delivery_days`  DESC
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try using outer joins:

```
SELECT
  ub.*,
  ub.document_date as ub_date,
  us.document_date as us_date,
  ul.document_date as ul_date,
  DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, ub.document_date) as total_days_delivery,
  DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, us.document_date) as total_days_assembly,
  DATEDIFF(us.document_date, ub.document_date) as total_days_order
FROM
  document_histories ub
  LEFT JOIN document_histories us ON us.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id AND us.document_type = 'us'
  LEFT JOIN document_histories ul ON ul.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id AND ul.document_type = 'ul'
WHERE
  ub.document_type = 'ub'
```

edit for aggregation:

```
SELECT
  ub.*,
  ub.document_date as ub_date,
  us.document_date as us_date,
  ul.document_date as ul_date,
  DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, ub.document_date) as total_days_delivery,
  DATEDIFF(ul.document_date, us.document_date) as total_days_assembly,
  DATEDIFF(us.document_date, ub.document_date) as total_days_order
FROM
  document_histories ub
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      assembly_order_id,document_date 
    FROM document_histories 
    WHERE 
      document_type = 'us' 
    ORDER BY 
      document_date ASC -- Change ASC/DESC respectively
    LIMIT 1) us ON us.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      assembly_order_id,document_date 
    FROM document_histories 
    WHERE 
      document_type = 'ul' 
    ORDER BY 
      document_date DESC -- Change ASC/DESC respectively
    LIMIT 1) ul ON ul.assembly_order_id = ub.assembly_order_id
WHERE
  ub.document_type = 'ub'
```

Comment: Using your edited code, I get a lot of null values in the us_date, ul_date en total columns, is the "LEFT JOIN" the right one to use?

Comment: You can use INNER JOIN to get only results that have all 3 document_types - ub,us,ul